# Event Receivers in SharePoint 2013

Tags: permissions, groups

I have a scenario where I have to develop multiple event receivers, on which I want your help.

the scenario is :

I have a list say "userlist" with two columns as "Title" and "username" and a SharePoint User Group say "Project Visitor".

username field is of type "People or Groups"

now what i want is, if anyone enter a record in the userlist then the name selected in username should be added to the Project Visitors group, in the same way, if that particular item is updated or deleted in the list then the change should also reflect in the SharePoint group.

the whole thing should also work in reverse as well, means if I add, update or delete any member in the group then the change should reflect in the list as well

how can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create the Event receiver as explained in example here : [How to create a custom list level event receiver in SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint 2010](http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/How-to-create-a-custom-list-level-event-receiver-in-SharePoint-2013-and-SharePoint-2010)

Or the other example you can use here: [Creating a simple Event Receiver in SharePoint 2013](http://onceinawhilescribble.blogspot.in/2013/05/creating-simple-event-receiver-in.html).

Once you create the event receiver, you can place code of adding current user to group, see this link here: [Add a user programmatically to a User Group in SharePoint](http://geekswithblogs.net/madhawa/archive/2008/11/18/127171.aspx).

You can simply manage operation as per the list item event, whether `userlist` item is being deleted or updated, there are separate event receiver methods available.

You can also remove the current user from group. There are some methods explained here you see for reference here: [Get, Add or Remove SharePoint groups and users programmatically](https://naimmurati.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/get-add-or-remove-sharepoint-groups-and-users-programmatically/).

For the reverse functionality, you can attach users and group level event receiver explained here: [Create GroupUserAdded Event Receiver in SharePoint 2013](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/create-groupuseradded-event-receiver-in-sharepoint-2013/),
List of Event receiver in SharePoint 2013 for Groups, Users etc: [SharePoint 2013 – New Event Receiver for Groups,Users,Roles,Inheritance](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/08/28/sharepoint-2013-new-event-receiver-for-groupsusersrolesinheritance/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to two event handlers

1. Attached to the List

   You need to `ItemUpdated` and `ItemAdded` events
2. Attached to SharePoint User Events - `SPSecurityEventReceiver` class was introduced to help developers add Event Handlers around SharePoint Groups, Users, Roles and Permission Inheritance.

   You can create this handler in a Feature Receiver

   ```
   SPEventReceiverDefinition grpUserAdded = web.EventReceivers.Add();
   grpUserAdded.Name = "Event Receiver GroupUserAdded";
   grpUserAdded.Type = SPEventReceiverType.GroupUserAdded;
   grpUserAdded.Assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName;
   grpUserAdded.Class = "GroupUserAddedEventReceiver.UserAddedEventReceiver";
   grpUserAdded.Update();

   web.Update();

   class UserAddedEventReceiver : SPSecurityEventReceiver
   {
       public override void GroupUserAdded(SPSecurityEventProperties properties)
       {
           base.GroupUserAdded(properties);

           //Get the user being added
           SPUser addedUser = properties.Web.AllUsers.GetByID(properties.GroupUserId);

           SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
           {
               if (addedUser != null && properties.GroupId == 8)
               {
                   SPGroup spGroup = properties.Web.Groups["Added Members"];

                   if (spGroup != null)
                   spGroup.AddUser(addedUser);
               }
           });
       }           
   }
   ```

   http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/12/27/create-a-groupuseradded-spsecurityeventreceiver-eventreceiver-in-sharepoint-2013-part-2/

Comment: According to the OP's requirements, he will also need `ItemDeleting` on the list to remove the user from the group if the list item is deleted.

Comment: @DylanCristy Yes. I was just pointing him in the right Direction. :)